# Choosing values on a variable depend on other variables

Tags: r, dplyr

In this dataframe, for each unique acount I have many unique user. For each acount I have a cost variable by month. Here I want to create a new variable cost2 for example where I keep only cost respecting the following condition :
* for each month, I want to keep only cost for only one account and others equal to zero

```
acount <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1)
user <- c(1:12, 2)
month <- c(201501, 201501, 201502, 201503, 201503, 201501, 
           201501, 201501, 201502, 201503, 201503, 201501, 201505)
cost <- c(30, 30 , 25, 40 , 40, 20, 20, 17, 17, -20, 18, 13, 0)

df <- data.frame(acount, user, month, cost)
```

For example for the account 1, I want to keep in cost2 the followings values : 30, 25, 0

I'm trying to do it with the ifelse statement but I'm stuck ...
Thank you

Comment: not really, what I want is for each month keeping only one cost value by acount. this value will be in cost2 but the other acount-user it will be zero for this month (sorry for my english)

Comment: Is this what you want? `df %>% group_by(acount, month) %>% summarise(cost2 = cost[1])`

Comment: Yes this is it, thank you but is it possible to keep the other user and make there cost2 equal to zero ?

Comment: Maybe `df %>% group_by(acount, month) %>% mutate(cost2 = ifelse(row_number(cost) == 1, cost, 0))`

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what I was looking for !
Please can you answer below, I will accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(acount, month) %>% 
  mutate(cost2 = ifelse(row_number(cost) == 1, cost, 0))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
#Groups: acount, month [10]
#
#   acount  user  month  cost cost2
#    (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1       1     1 201501    30    30
#2       1     2 201501    30     0
#3       1     3 201502    25    25
#4       2     4 201503    40    40
#5       2     5 201503    40     0
#6       2     6 201501    20    20
#7       2     7 201501    20     0
#8       3     8 201501    17    17
#9       3     9 201502    17    17
#10      3    10 201503   -20   -20
#11      4    11 201503    18    18
#12      4    12 201501    13    13
#13      1     2 201505     0     0
```